# Elasticsearch, nested type, how to get a sum of the doc_count of all items in bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregate, aggregation

use the same example as the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908712/elasticsearch-aggregation-order-by-nested-bucket-doc-count). say that the both fields, `address.city` and `address.stateOrProvince` are nested type, and the aggregation does NOT specify `"nested":{"path":<nested path>}`. The aggregation result does not have the sum of the doc_count. Since the `"nested":{"path":<nested path>}` is not specified, the root level doc_count at the root level hit is not the sum of the doc_count in bucket either.

[edited], added the examples as Val's comment, the `activities` is nested type. query1 has `"nested":{"path":<nested path>"}` specified but query2 not. In result2, how to have the sum of the doc_count of all items in bucket, which is 2+1+1+1 in this case.

//doc1

```
{
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:49:35.687Z",
"activities.duration": "18747",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:49:54.639Z",
"activities.duration": "65",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:49:56.737Z",
"activities.duration": "449",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:49:56.772Z",
"activities.duration": "412"}
```

//doc2

```
{
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:55:43.304Z",
"activities.duration": "18675",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:56:02.150Z",
"activities.duration": "88",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:56:04.269Z",
"activities.duration": "396",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:56:04.314Z",
"activities.duration": "349"}
```

//doc3

```
{
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:49:56.087Z",
"activities.duration": "18723",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:50:15.002Z",
"activities.duration": "77",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:50:17.125Z",
"activities.duration": "418",
"activities.entry.time": "2015-09-15T17:50:17.137Z",
"activities.duration": "404"}
```

//query1

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "dim0": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "activities"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "dh": {
                "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "activities.entry.time",
                    "interval": "minute",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    "pre_zone": -7
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "avg_duration": {
                        "avg": {
                            "field": "activities.duration"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

//result1

```
{
"took": 3,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "dim0": {
        "doc_count": 12,
        "dh": {
            "buckets": [{
                "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
                "key": 1442339340000,     //2015-09-15T17:49:00.000Z
                "doc_count": 5,           //4 count in doc1 + 1 count in doc3
                "avg_duration": {
                    "value": 7679.2       //(18747+65+449+412+18723) / 5
                }
            }, {
                "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
                "key": 1442339400000,     //2015-09-15T17:50:00.000Z
                "doc_count": 3,
                "avg_duration": {
                    "value": 299.6666666666667
                }
            }, {
                "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
                "key": 1442339700000,     //2015-09-15T17:55:00.000Z
                "doc_count": 1,
                "avg_duration": {
                    "value": 18675.0
                }
            }, {
                "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
                "key": 1442339760000,     //2015-09-15T17:56:00.000Z
                "doc_count": 3,
                "avg_duration": {
                    "value": 277.6666666666667
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}}
```

//query2

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "dh": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "activities.entry.time",
            "interval": "minute",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "pre_zone": -7
        },
        "aggs": {
            "avg_duration": {
                "avg": {
                    "field": "activities.duration"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

//result2

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "dh": {
        "buckets": [{
            "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
            "key": 1442339340000, //2015-09-15T17:49:00.000Z
            "doc_count": 2,       //doc1 + doc3
            "avg_duration": {
                "value": 4911.875 //(18747+65+449+412)+(18723+77+418+404)/8
            }
        }, {
            "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
            "key": 1442339400000, //2015-09-15T17:50:00.000Z
            "doc_count": 1,
            "avg_duration": {
                "value": 4905.5
            }
        }, {
            "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
            "key": 1442339700000, //2015-09-15T17:55:00.000Z
            "doc_count": 1,
            "avg_duration": {
                "value": 4877.0
            }
        }, {
            "key_as_string": "2015-09-15",
            "key": 1442339760000, //2015-09-15T17:56:00.000Z
            "doc_count": 1,
            "avg_duration": {
                "value": 4877.0
            }
        }]
    }
}}
```

Comment: I think that in the question you linked to, the author meant `nested` in the sense of "nested fields inside an object" and not `nested` type per se. I'm sure, though, what you question is. Can you show us your current query, what you're getting and what you expect? It will be easier for people to help you out.

Comment: thanks Val, examples have been added.

Comment: A first question would be why don't you use a `nested` aggregation in your second query?

Comment: both queries make sense as they are for different use cases. that could be reason elasticsearch allow non-nested aggregation by nested field, and up to user to design used nested aggregation or not.