# Elasticsearch query that prevents same value of a field appear next to each other

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have some docs like this:

```
{
  "text": "sample - very high relevancy",
  "myField": "a1"
},
{
  "text": "sample - less relevancy",
  "myField": "a2"
},
{
  "text": "sample - high relevancy",
  "myField": "a1"
},
{
  "text": "sample - very less relevancy",
  "myField": "a3"
}
```

I've wrote a query of search similarity and stuff... I'm trying to sort it like never two same `myField` values appear next to each other.

I want to all distinct values of `myField` appears to top of results, then the duplicate ones.

**What i'm looking for** is an advanced sorting query that
lowers the score of a document if it's field `myField` already appeared in the result.

*According to my example, I expect my result to be*:

```
{
  "text": "sample - very high relevancy",
  "myField": "a1"
},
{
  "text": "sample - less relevancy",
  "myField": "a2"
},
 {
  "text": "sample - very less relevancy",
  "myField": "a3"
},
{
  "text": "sample - high relevancy",
  "myField": "a1"
},
{
  "text": "sample - extremely less relevancy",
  "myField": "a5"
}
```

High relevancy field appeared on bottom of results cause `a1` value already appeared in the top and other fields `a2` `a3` is more important for me.
Also if a document is so unrelevant to our query should be at the most bottom no matter if it's `myField` value is not appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation and alter its sorting behavior.

Below pseudo query should work (as I don't have a running elastic):
Aggregation is used to club duplicate results into one bucket.

Sorting is applied on the [buckets count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952843/how-do-i-sort-buckets-by-term-aggregations-nested-doc-count) so that buckets with count 1 come at top.

```
{
"query" : {
  // Your search query/filter goes here
},
"aggs": {
  "myagg": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "myField",
      "order": {
        "myagg>_count" : "asc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, What should i replace with `myagg>_count` ?

Comment: Use any useful name for your aggregation ex. myagg. Then use aggname>_count in order block. Let me know if the query works as you expected.